# Doubt in the defn of exponential operator.

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

**definition**

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Then for $t\in \mathbb R$,
$$e^{At}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^kt^k}{k!}\tag{1}$$

But in this definition, What they are meaning by the term $A^kt^k$, If I give this matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\2&3\end{pmatrix},$$

what can we say about the $(1)$, means  How it will be?

Comment: From [FAQ about tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/128#128): *Try to avoid creating new tags. Instead, check if there is some synonym that already has a popular tag.* It's not easy to keep balance between too specific tags and not having enough tags, but it is always good to search first and to ask yourself, whether newly created tag is not too specific. (Of course, you can disagree with the removal of the tag you've created, and there is possibility for further discussion, if needed.)

Comment: In this particular case you have created two new tags [tag:exponential-operators] and [tag:linearsystem]. For the first, it is not clear what the tag is supposed to be for. In the second case, I don't really see how it is related to the question. You have not created tag-wikis for the new tags. (Which is a good practice, tag-creator should indicate what the tag is intended for.) Similar questions have been quite often tagged [matrices+exponential-function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices+exponential-function) (or using some similar tags).

Comment: The section i have chosen for this question deals with linear system of ode.. thats why i relates this...

Comment: A reasonable tags for systems of ODEs are (not-surprisingly) [ode+systems-of-equations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ode+systems-of-equations). I don't think we have tags specifically for linear systems of odes, but I might be wrong.

Comment: oh.. thankyou for the calrifications...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this kind of problem is to find the [Jordan Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of $A$:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1-i&-1+i\\
2&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2-i&0\\
0&2+i
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1-i&-1+i\\
2&2
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
Taking the exponential of $A$ is now pretty simple:
$$
\begin{align}
\exp(At)&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1-i&-1+i\\
2&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2t}e^{-it}&0\\
0&e^{2t}e^{it}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1-i&-1+i\\
2&2
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
-1-i&-1+i\\
2&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2t}e^{-it}&0\\
0&e^{2t}e^{it}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2i&1+i\\
-2i&1-i
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(t)-\sin(t)&-\sin(t)\\
2\sin(t)&\cos(t)+\sin(t)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: what is $At$ means?? Does this mean that  multipling every entries of A by t??@robjohn

Comment: Yes. Just plain scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

To do exponentiation of matrices, the easiest way is to diagonalize the exponent first,

$U^{\dagger} AtU =  D = \mbox{diag}\{D_1, D_2,...,D_n\}  $ with eigen values $D_1,D_2,...,D_n$

since

$ U^{\dagger}exp(At) U = exp(D) = \mbox{diag}\{e^{D_1}, e^{D_2},...,e^{D_n} \} $
Then 
$$exp(At) = U exp(D)U^{\dagger} $$

For you matrix, you will get,

$$ e^{At} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{2 t} \cos (t)-e^{2 t} \sin (t) & -e^{2 t} \sin (t) \\
 2 e^{2 t} \sin (t) & e^{2 t} \cos (t)+e^{2 t} \sin (t) \\
\end{array}
\right) .$$

Comment: for a non-diagonalizable matrices?????????@mastrok

Comment: what is $A^kt^k$..??@mastrok

Comment: $A$ is a matrix while $t$ is just a pure number, $A^k$ means $k$ $A$'s are multiplied with each other under matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question $(1)$ will be

$$ e^{At} = \left[ \begin {array}{cc} {{\rm e}^{2\,t}}(\cos \left( t \right)- \sin \left( t \right)) &-{{\rm e}^{2\,t}}\sin \left( t
 \right) \\ 2\,{{\rm e}^{2\,t}}\sin \left( t
 \right) & {{\rm e}^{2\,t}}(\cos \left( t \right) +\sin\left( t \right)) \end {array} \right] .$$